What is faster and more efficient for a swap on Solana: using an aggregator like Jupiter or a tip with Jito?
When implementing a swap via code on Solana, is it faster or more effective to use:
A swap aggregator like Jupiter, or
A priority fee (tip) with Jito (using raydium)?
Does this choice affect the transaction speed, or does it only impact the likelihood of the transaction being accepted by the network?
I’d appreciate any insights regarding how these approaches compare in terms of speed and efficiency when implemented programmatically.

It's important to distinguish the difference between programs and sending, which are conflated in the question. Let's disentangle them.
Programs: first, you want to distinguish between using Jupiter or Raydium's on-chain programs. In general, when choosing to include a transaction, the leader will consider the accounts touched by your transaction and the priority fee paid. Since Jupiter has the option of routing through Raydium, or other protocols, it will most likely touch more accounts than just Raydium, so going straight to Raydium is probably easier for landing a transaction.
Sending mechanism: looking at the Jupiter docs at https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/landing-transactions, they suggest using a special RPC server just for Jupiter. Unfortunately, I don't know about their implementation, but I imagine they have some stake-weighted quality of service on that endpoint to help their transactions arrive at the leader. This mechanism would help transactions land with any leader, not just nodes running Jito. On the other hand, Jito's priority marketplace is supposed to ensure that transactions land, but they only work with Jito nodes. Since ~80% of the network is running Jito, it's most likely safest to use the Jito tipping mechanism if you want your transaction to land, but it will likely cost more in transaction fees.
So all of those words to say: it depends! But in general, I imagine you transactions will land more often hitting Raydium directly with a Jito tip.
